# How to implement JWT Refresh Tokens in asp.net core web api (no 3rd party)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm in the process of implementing a web api using asp.net core that is using JWT. I am not using a third party solution such as IdentityServer4 as I am trying to learn.

I've gotten the JWT configuration to work, but am stumped on how to implement refresh tokens for when the JWT's expire.

Below is some sample code in my Configure method inside startup.cs.

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Jwt",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    }
});
```

Below is the Controller method used to generate the JWT. I have set expiration to 30 seconds for testing purposes.

```
    [Route("Token")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody] CredentialViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (_hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, model.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

                    var claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                    }.Union(userClaims);

                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwt.Key));
                    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            issuer: _jwt.Issuer,
                            audience: _jwt.Audience,
                            claims: claims,
                            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30),
                            signingCredentials: creds
                        );

                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                        expiration = token.ValidTo
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return BadRequest("Failed to generate token.");
    }
```

Would be very grateful for some guidance.

Comment: The code you posted is only relevant to authenticating access tokens, not refresh tokens. Can you share the code where you generate access tokens?

Comment: Sure, I have added the code used to generate the JWT's.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, you need to generate a refresh token and persist it somewhere. This is because you want to be able to invalidate it if needed. If you were to follow the same pattern as an access token - where all the data is contained within the token - a token that ends up in the wrong hands can the be used to generate new access tokens for the lifetime of the refresh token, which can be a really long time.

So what the heck do you need to persist?

You need a unique identifier of some sort that's not easy guessable, a GUID will do just fine. You also need the data to be able to issue a new access token, most likely a username. Having a username you can then skip the VerifyHashedPassword(...)-part but for the rest of it, just follow the same logic.

To obtain a refresh token, you normally use the scope "offline_access", this being something that you provide in your model (CredentialViewModel) when making a token request. Unlike a normal access token request, you don't need to provide your username and password, but instead the refresh token. When getting a request with a refresh token, you lookup the persisted identifier and issue a token for the user found.

Following is pseudo code for the happy path:

```
[Route("Token")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody] CredentialViewModel model)
{
    if (model.GrantType is "refresh_token")
    {
        // Lookup which user is tied to model.RefreshToken
        // Generate access token from the username (no password check required)
        // Return the token (access + expiration)
    }
    else if (model.GrantType is "password")
    {
        if (model.Scopes contains "offline_access")
        {
            // Generate access token
            // Generate refresh token (random GUID + model.username)
            // Persist refresh token
            // Return the complete token (access + refresh + expiration)
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate access token
            // Return the token (access + expiration)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply possible to Generate a RefreshToken the same way as you create the AccessToken.
But as naslund said, other than the AccessToken you should persist your refreshToken anywhere into DB, etc. to add the possiblilty to mark it as invalid.
Additionally I would recommend to use the Role "refresh" for your refreshToken to mark him as beeing allowed to beused for the Refresh Endpoint.

So following Steps are needed when generation an new token pair using refreshToken.

1. Check that token is still valid and Role is "refresh" (will be handled by authorized Property)
2. Check that the Token is still active(DB Check or wherever you stored the token)
3. Create new Pair for Session.
4. Add/Update RefreshToken Entry in DB to hold your new Refresh token.
5. Send the new Access Token + Refresh Token to the User Application.

In Code:

```
class AuthResponse {
    public string AccessToken { get;set; }
    public string RefreshToken {get;set; }
}


class LoginRequest {
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}

class AuthenticationController {
    [Unauthorized]
    public ActionResult<AuthResponse> Login(loginRequest login){
        //Create TokenPair
    }
    [Authorized(Role = "refresh")]
    public ActionResult<AuthResponse> Refresh(){
        //Load RefreshToken from Request
        //Create TokenPair
    }
    [Authorized(Role = "refresh")]
    public ActionResult<bool> Logout(){
        //Mark Token as invalid
        return true;
    }
}
```