# Generate new JWT on every API call

Tags: .net, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I'm brand new to .NET development, so please don't assume I understand all of the basics (i.e. please use small words, I'm not offended by any assumptions that I'm dumb).

I'm implementing token-based authentication and have spent many hours Googling for answers. I've gotten to the point where I can generate a JWT and return it in an API call, reject unauthorized API calls, and accept authorized API calls.

My token is set to expire 30 minutes after being issued. My intention is to consider the user logged out after 30 minutes of inactivity. So on each API call, I want to issue a new JWT with a new 30 minute expiration, and the client will need to replace the stored token on each call.

Obviously, I could call something like `var token = TokenService.GenerateToken()` for every API endpoint, but that seems cumbersome.

I'm wondering if there's a sanctioned way to set it up so that it is automatically generated and appended to each authorized call? Or am I going about this the wrong way and implementing a wonky solution?

Comment: I think you need to look at the concept of refreshing the token. Have a read of this answer as a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/a/43482929/540156

Comment: @onefootswill: I have read about refresh tokens, but I couldn't figure out why they would be beneficial to me. It seems like it just adds an extra call required by the client to get a new token every so often. I'm basically doing the same thing here, but the new token gets generated automatically on every call instead of making the client do a separate call just to get a new token. Not sure if it's relevant, but "Remember me" functionality is not a concern for my project. So why go to the trouble of storing refresh tokens and making extra calls for the client?

Comment: I can't claim to be an expert in this field, but my understanding is that refresh tokens is the best practice for this sort of thing. So, I honestly could not say whether you need to use them or not. Issuing a new token with every hit to the server seems to go against the grain of things a bit. But like I said, I'm no expert. In my work, when I feel like I'm fighting against a technology, I step back and re-assess. Perhaps take a good look at refressh tokens.The extra call you were concerned about will be negligible.

Comment: @Travesty3 if you approach problem that way then why generate new token on every request at all? why not just make its lifetime 100 years from the begining? because thats what you are effectively doing. your generation of new one has no meaning except using server resources for no gain.

Comment: @deezg: The token has a 30 minute expiration. If there is no activity for 30 minutes, the token expires and the user has to reauthenticate.

Comment: what happens if user was active for 20 mins, had 21427 requests and then in 21st minute, you change his role and need to revoke his active tokens immediately in order to prevent him accessing resources he should not have access to anymore?

Comment: what happens if your client is some app whose developer screwed up thing and don't use new token on each request, he changes his email in user profile in one request, but then send old token (containing old email address) in new request and you don't check anything but token expiry & overall validity like not being tampered?

Comment: @deezg: Being able to invalidate a token does seem to be main argument for using the access/refresh token setup, but imagine your first scenario with access/refresh tokens. I have an access token that will have some expiration on it (usually around 30 minutes from what I've seen). My refresh token expires in 30 days. I can invalidate the refresh token, but I cannot invalidate an access token. So if the user re-uses the same access token within the 30 minute window, the database is not re-checked, so they can still access resources they shouldn't have access to anymore, right?

Comment: @deezg: I also don't understand how an access/refresh token would resolve your second scenario. If the developer screwed up and never stores a new token, then whether it was implemented using my solution above or via access/refresh tokens, the same thing happens. Their old info is stored in the token they're sending back to me instead of the new info. If anything, I would think the access/refresh token would be more susceptible to failure since the client would have to make a separate call to get a new access token after their info changed instead of it being created automatically every time.

Comment: well, if you cannot revoke access token then you just have wrong implementation (assuming you need revokation, of course). btw, db is not the only way to implement token white/black lists. / on the other hand, the purpose of refresh token is not only to 'remember me' but to shorten attacker time window. so even if they get their hands on access token, they have very limited time to perform attack before expiry. getting refresh tolen, if implemented per specs, is much harder thus much less likely. with your implementation, once they get access token they get access pretty much forever.

Comment: my point with second scenario was that you have a ton of reduntant informations to keep an eye on instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

There has two type of tokens, one is Access token, another is Refresh token. I don't think you should do sliding expiration as it will make the access token vulnerable.(If somebody have the token and could use it to hack your system). For Access token, it should have short-live time. and client should use refresh token with client id to acquire a new access token.

Sometimes try to do too much for client app could compromise your system security.It should be client's job to use refresh token before the expiration time.

And I think OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions class has everything you need to make it happen.

Comment: How does having a "sliding expiration" make the access token vulnerable? Even if I use an access token/refresh token combo, then if someone gets the access token, they can still access the system just the same. And if someone can get the access token, it seems very likely to me that they could also just as easily get the refresh token. Sure, I may have the ability to invalidate a refresh token if it is found to be compromised, but until that point, how is this more secure?

Comment: let me explain the difference between Access token and Refresh token first. The Access token has all the necessary information to access the resource, no Auth server involve needed.  With Refresh token, it will have to contact Auth server to get a new access token. The server could blacklist the refresh token if needed.  Now you see the difference, if someone have the access token and that token has long-live time span, you lost the control to revoke his access by using the Auth server.

Comment: @TedZhang but if you're refreshing the token on each call like the OP describes, then you can also blacklist it if each refresh stores it in a db for example. The difference probably isn't so much about security but maybe performance, reducing calls to the auth server with the access / refresh setup.